# PHP Multiple Upload - Ignore upload code

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

For my internship, I need to built a webapp using PHP, the goal of the application is to make notes using voice recognition technology (javascript).

One part of the "make-a-note" section is the ability to upload multiple images/files. The notes and images that are related are stored in 2 different tables, and are linked based on the NoteID.

```
  $countfiles = count($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);
  $note_query = "INSERT INTO Notes(NOTS_ID, NOTS_V_USRS, NOTS_V_ORGS, NOTS_A_TITLE, NOTS_A_TEXT, NOTS_C_TAGS, NOTS_V_CTRY, NOTS_T_FROM, NOTS_T_UNTIL) VALUES ('0', '" . $usr_id['USRS_ID'] . "','" . $organisation . "', '" . $note_title .  "', '" . $note_text . "', '0', '" . $country . "', '" . $fromdate . "', '" . $untildate . "');";
   $conn->query($note_query) or die($conn->error());
   $lastid = $conn->insert_id;
  $imagedata  = array();
  // FILE UPLOAD 
  if (isset($_FILES['images'])){

    for($i=0; $i < $countfiles; $i++){
      $file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
      array_push($imagedata, $file_name);
      $desired_dir="./uploads/imgs/";
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $desired_dir.$file_name);
       $img_query = "INSERT INTO Images(IMGS_ID, IMGS_V_USRS, IMGS_T_NAME, IMGS_V_NOTS) VALUES ('0', '" . $usr_id['USRS_ID'] . "', '" . $desired_dir.$file_name . "', '" . $lastid . "');";
       $conn->query($img_query);
      }
  }
```

The part in the form where the file gets selected: 
 `<input type="file" name="images[] multiple">`

When I fill in the form, and upload for example 2 images, it just skips over the code, meaning, no files get uploaded/inserted in the database. 
The "Note" part is added correctly.

Any suggestion on how come this does not work? Or what do I need to change?

Thanks alot!

Regards,
Dries :)

EDIT `enctype=multipart/form-data` is also added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put in the form enctype?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it in my question, yes I did! :)

Comment: I expect that your form is like this:
`<input name="images[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`

// Count # of uploaded files in array
`$total = count($_FILES['images']['name']);`

what value shows in this part?
`var_dump($total );`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response! putting in the code you said returns this: int(2) (i uploaded 2 photos) so i guess thats fine :) adding no files returns int(1)

Comment: can you put your full form html? I need to know if you put it like this "<input type="file" name="images[] multiple">" becase thats wrong need to be "<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>"